# How to change appearance in Sekiro?

Tags: sekiro-shadows-die-twice

I was stumbling upon [this speeedrun video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IusDQUDAJng), where the character looks totally not like the default one. So I was wondering how I could change my look as well. I couldn't find anything within the game about this. Also my few searches on the web were not successful.

**How can I change the appearance of Sekiro?**

Do I need to tamper with the game files (like renaming files)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be [ZullieTheWitch](https://www.nexusmods.com/sekiro/users/34738570)'s [Costume Pack Mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/sekiro/mods/93).

Screenshot for comparison: [image: Screenshot of a modded player character in Sekiro]